# Combine multiple plugins into one?

Tags: plugins, installation

I've collected a few plugins that each have specific functionality I need for what would otherwise be a single large plugin.

Is it possible to bundle these into a single installable zip?

Comment: Because its possible, doesn't mean it should be done. I don't see any logical reason to doing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go through each plugin file and remove the plugin header.
2. Create a loader.php file.

Something like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Combined Plugin
Description: Contains plugin a, plugin b and plugin c
*/

include dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin-a.php';
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin-b.php';
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin-c.php';
```

Comment: OK, I've created a folder called "my-plugin-collection" and I've copied each of the plugin folders into that folder. Next, I create your loader.php file and reference each of the plugin folder's plugin.php files, correct? Hoping this works even when the plugins are complex and have subfolders...

Comment: Note that any plugins combined in this manner will not get update notifications or be displayed within the main plugins list. If you use a WP management system like InfiniteWP or ManageWP, they will not be able to update the individual plugins either.